gsap pin property of a react component affect the animation of below component
I made a website using react and gsap in which i created a video playing effect on scrolling and pin it.
but due to this it affect the animation of its below side component , I have find the reason behind this but i dont have idea to solve it. according to me its happening because the pin property hold the component on the screen and on scrolling the animation starting and ending of below components also scrolled up due to this when we reach to below component its animation points is gone . in the result animation of that compo. is not performed..
https://github.com/ibnegufran/react-portfoilio-/blob/main/src/components/works.jsx
this is my link of video playing effect component
i want to resolve this issue and both property should work properly
